# C ++ Issue with map and the Compare Class

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I was hoping maybe someone could help me solve my issue. I get a lovely

> No matching function for call to object of type 'const pCompare'

```
struct pCompare
 {
    bool operator()( const std::string & str1, const std::string & str2 ) const
    {
        return str1.compare( str2 ) == 0;
    }
 };
 std::string *t = new std::string ( "/test.html" );
 std::map<std::string*, std::string, pCompare> test;
 test.insert ( std::pair<std::string*, std::string> ( t, "héhé" ) );
 std::cout << test.find(new std::string ("/test.html") )->second;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your map has `(const) string *` as keys yet your comparator takes `const string &`...

Comment: Is it possible to change your implementation to use `std::map<std::string, std::string>`. Using values instead of pointers can make things a lot easier.

Comment: Also note that comparators should test for ordering not equality otherwise you go into UB land.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, do not do this, as it will screw up your map: You need an ordering function for the map, not an equality test.

Anyway, I guess you problem is that your key type std::string* but your function tests for string& . I haven't tried this, but this should do the trick:

```
bool operator()( std::string * str1, const std::string * str2 ) const
{
    return *str1 < *str2;
}
```

Comment: I did forgot the treee part of the map, my bad... In anyway the reference was the issue